# Visual Studio - Default code generation is disabled

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-4

I am trying to follow this tutorial that uses the Entity Data Model.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/create-first-simple-EDM.aspx
It tells me to open the Model1.designer.cs file.
I should see a bunch of C# code but all I see is:

```
// Default code generation is disabled for model 'c:\users\dewi jones\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\dewi_test\dewi_test\Dewi_Model.edmx'. 
// To enable default code generation, change the value of the 'Code Generation Strategy' designer
// property to an alternate value. This property is available in the Properties Window when the model is
// open in the designer.
```

I have tried to enable code generation but I can't figure out how. I can't see it in the project properties :( 
I am new to Visual basic and would greatly appreciate help. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Open the [Model Browser Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738483%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of your entity model in Visual Studio, navigate to Properties window(hit `[F4]`) and change the `Code Generation Strategy` to `Default`

[image: Model Properties Window]

Comment: Thanks very much. But it's still just showing the large commend and no code :(  
Any way to generate the code? Thanks

Comment: did you save your model after changing the generation template? what is the code generation template used?